# The computation of the Laplacian of the heat kernel on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

From John Roe, *Elliptic Operators, topology and asymptotic methods* , page 99

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ with fixed point $q$. Let a geodesic local coordinate system $x^{i}$ originate from $q$. Let $r^{2}=\sum(x^{i})^{2}=\sum g^{ij}x^{i}x^{j}$(is there a typo here?), so that $r$ is the geodesic distance from $q$ and $h$ is the function 
$$
(4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{4t}}
$$
Roe claimed the following:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}+\triangle h=\frac{rh}{4gt}\frac{\partial g}{\partial r},g=\det(g_{ij})
$$
I could not really follow his proof for this statement. After establishing the fact that $\nabla h=-\frac{h}{2t}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, he wants to apply the formula
$$
\nabla^{*}(fV)=f\nabla^{*}V-\langle \nabla f, V\rangle
$$
where $f=-\frac{h}{2t}$, $V=r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ to $\nabla h$, thus compute the Laplacian. To compute the first part, he claimed that
$$
\nabla^{*}(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\sum_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}(x^{j}\sqrt{g})=-n-\frac{r}{2g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}
$$
I am very puzzled with this computation. He used the formula that for a one form $\alpha=\sum A_{i}dx_{i}$ we have
$$
d^{*}\alpha=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\sum_{i,j}\partial_{j}(A_{i}g^{ij}\sqrt{g})
$$
Thus since $rdr\leftrightarrow r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ by identifying $TM$ with $T^{*}M$, he get the above formula. Now I have some questions:

1) How do we exactly write down $r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ in local coordinates? Should it be $\sum (r\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial r})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$? But then how to compute $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial r}$ using the metric?

2) Assuming $A_{i}g^{ij}=x^{j}$ for now, how do we compute
$$
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\sum_{j}x_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\sqrt{g}?
$$
I remember Roe has computed $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\log{\sqrt{g}}$ earlier using Cramer's rule, and the result is(see page 20, there may be a typo here)
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\log{\sqrt{g}}=\sum_{\alpha}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{j\alpha}
$$
But now all the Christoffel symbols has 'miraculously' disappeared, and it is replaced by
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}
$$
which I again do not know how to compute. So I need to ask for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one piece of the puzzle you are missing is that
$$ r \partial_r = \sum_i x^i \partial_i.$$
This means that
$$ - \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \sum_i x^i \partial_i \sqrt{g}  = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} r \partial_r (\sqrt{g} ) = -\frac{r}{2g} \partial_r g,$$
as claimed.

---

Edit: I think there is some confusing notation at work here. It seems Roe uses $\nabla$ to mean two different things: for most of the book, he uses it to denote a connection on a bundle $S$, which is a map
$$ \nabla: \Gamma(S) \to \Gamma(T^\ast M \otimes S).$$
In this context, on the other hand, he uses $\nabla$ to denote the gradient, which gives the direction of greatest increase of a function:
$$ \nabla = \text{grad} : C^\infty(M) \to \Gamma(TM).$$
Each of these $\nabla$'s have a formal adjoint $\nabla^\ast$ going the other way; in this proof, it seems that $\nabla^\ast$ refers to the adjoint of the gradient operator, which is usually called the divergence (actually, I think the usual divergence is the negative of this). From now on in this answer, I will use the notation $\text{grad}$ for the gradient and $\text{div}$ for the divergence. In coordinates, these operators are given by
\begin{align*}
\text{grad} \, f &= \sum_{i,j} g^{ij} \partial_i f \, \partial_j \\
\text{div}(X^i \partial_i)  &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \sum_i \partial_i (X^i \sqrt{g})
\end{align*}
(Note the sign on $\text{div}$, which is probably not standard. These formulas can be found in Jost, for example.)

The Laplacian of a function $f$ can be computed in (at least) two ways:
$$\Delta f = d^\ast d f = \text{div} \, \text{grad} \, f.$$
It seems that Roe is computing $\Delta h$ as $\text{div} \, \text{grad} \, h$, although he uses the notation $\nabla^\ast \nabla h$. I think it is a mistake when he refers to formula 1.26, which is for $d^\ast$, not $\text{div}$ (perhaps in the first edition of the book, there was a formula for $\text{div}$).

Let's take a moment to compare $d^\ast$ and $\text{div}$, which are given by the very similar formulas
\begin{align*}
d^\ast (A_i dx^i) &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \sum_{i,j} \partial_j (A_i g^{ij} \sqrt{g})  \\
\text{div}(X^i \partial_i)  &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \sum_i \partial_i (X^i \sqrt{g})
\end{align*}
Note the appearance of the $g^{ij}$ in $d^\ast$. Interestingly, there is no nice "product rule" for $d^\ast$, whereas for $\text{div}$ we have (as Roe states) the following:
$$\text{div}(fV) = f \, \text{div} \, V - \langle \text{grad} \, f, V \rangle .$$

Comment: Thanks! This certainly helps.

Comment: Here is something I am confused about: Is $r$ a vector here, or just a scalar denoting the distance? I think Roe meant $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $dr$ as the direction $r$ increases most rapidly, but I felt confused with notation like $r\partial_{r}$.

Comment: @Bombyx mori, I added a clarification of his notation which I hope will clear some things up. I still owe you an explanation of the formula for $r \partial_r$, and further discussion of "$r$". Briefly though, $r$ is a scalar function, not a vector. It can also be viewed (locally) as a coordinate function (e.g., in geodesic polar coordinates). $\partial_r$ is the corresponding coordinate vector field.

Comment: Thanks! I need to read it carefully.

Comment: I have finished reading it. Thanks a lot for the clarification. May I ask why there is no "Leibniz rule" for $d^{*}$? I thought since $d^{*}$ is kind of a first order operator, some kind of product rule should hold.

Comment: You can see that there is no nice Leibniz rule for $d^\ast$ just by computing, say $d^\ast(f \omega) = \pm \ast d \ast (f \omega)$, where $f$ is a function and $\omega$ is a one-form. Or more generally, try to compute $d^\ast(\omega \wedge \eta)$ for forms $\omega$ and $\eta$. Of course, there is in some sense a "rule" for $d^\ast$ of a product, but it's not a nice, clean one like the graded Leibniz rule for $d$. (There's probably a precise sense in which it's not "nice" and a precise reason, but I don't know it.)